# Is it possible to do a radius constraint in Blender?

Tags: transforms, constraints

Is it possible to do a radius constraint in Blender? 
For example, consider 2 cubes, 1 unit apart, as the following;

```
[]--1 unit--[]
```

If we move the box on the right up or down, it will retain same distance as the following;

```
    []
    /
   1 unit 
  /
[]
```

This is not for Blender Game Engine, I simply want to set up constraints, but can't see of how to get it done in Blender.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [*Limit Distance*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Limit_Distance#Limit_Distance_Constraint) constraint.

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Transform/Limit_Distance#Description):

> The *Limit Distance* constraint forces its owner to stay either further from, nearer to, or exactly at a given distance from its target. In other words, the owner’s location is constrained either outside, inside, or at the surface of a sphere centered on its target.

Comment: Argh! Suddenly it appears my Blender screen, including Clamp Region on Surface that I needed!